# I am trying to get Access to do specific tasks

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access 2016, and here is my Access form:

[image]

When a new record is created, I need the user to click whether or not the clinical case is true. Moreover, I need the true/false options to be unmodifiable upon clicking and either a trueCase or falseCase instance is created. "True" and "False" will generate the values 1 and 2, respectively, and be stored in the statusTrueFalse field of my Cases table. I don't have any idea of how to proceed from there and would greatly appreciate the community's feedback/hints.

Here is my relationship diagram:

[image]

If true, I would like to have the open date/close date and reason closed fields appear. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the subform to a list box control with a row source equal to the original subform query.

You could then add macros to the AfterUpdate() event of the list box to show your True/False command buttons (Visible=True) when the user selects a row in the list box. Then add OnClick() events to the command buttons to make them  visible=false so they can only choose once.

Add any processing routines to the OnClick() event needed to capture the True vs. False values and store them in your table. You should be able to reference the list box control in your macro/code to choose the correct row in your table to update, or grab other information from the list box to generate a new record.

You might want to add a requery method to the command buttons OnClick() events to also filter any records that have already been answered true/false in the list box to avoid someone re-selecting a row they already answered and adding another True/False record.

Edit: AFAIK Access can't determine which row is selected in a subform, which is why I suggested using a list box instead.

Edit 2 (sorry): I missed your last question. You can have the date fields and reason for closure fields work the same way as your true/false command buttons. Make them visible=false by default and in the OnClick() event for the True command button, set those fields to visible=true, pause your code to wait for entries, then trigger off of another command button or AfterUpdate() event of the last field in your tab order to add the data to your table. Let me know if you need further explanation, I just finished a similar application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I am learning Access. For Edit 2: can I do this strictly from the side panel or do I need to use VBA? Sorry if it's an obvious question!

Comment: You can create a macro through your properties pane and by using the SetProperty command in the macro builder. No required VBA development.